# X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) ffmpeg error

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I'm getting the following error message in ffmpeg:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  4 (X_ShmGetImage)
  Serial number of failed request:  11
  Current serial number in output stream:  11
```

I turns up when I run the bash function [mentioned in a forum post about streaming in Linux](http://forums.heroesofnewerth.com/showthread.php?t=229469).

What does it mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to record a streaming video by playing it while `ffmpeg` records your screen to a file.

I think the problem is that

```
INRES="1920x1080"
```

doesn't match your actual screen resolution. When recording your X display (`-f x11grab`), if you mess up the input screen resolution, `ffmpeg` gives such a nasty error message. You need to change this line to match your monitor's actual resolution.